# Jira/xRay - Embedded element in JSON-Report has the wrong name in Jira

Tags: cucumber, jira, cucumber-junit, jira-xray

We are running Cucumber Tests and upload the results into Jira using the xRay Plugin.
The uploaded report is a cucumber json report.
Sometimes we attach files to the cucumber scenario and therefor to the report using:

`scenario.attach(logText, "text/plain", "log.txt");`

In the Report it looks like that:

`"embeddings": [{ "data": "loremipsum...", "mime_type": "text/plain", "name": "log.txt"  } ],`

But in Jira/ xRay the name is missing, the content and mime-type is correct:
[testrun in xRay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgAMD.png)

I would expect the same name in Jira/xRay (Screenshot) as in the "name" of the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xray doesn't process that information (i.e. the `name` attribute).
The Cucumber JSON format is not consistent across different client APIs and [there is no official JSON schema](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-json-converter) for it.
You can reach out to [Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) and ask for this new improvement. At least cucumber-jvm (the Java client) seems to generate the `embeddings` element with a `name` attribute, so in theory Xray could process it in the future.